# Insert any code in the method

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to write a plugin that start from a method,
and insert some code into the method.
But i don't know how to get the body of the method.
(the start position of the method)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the tutorial of Lars Vogel: http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJDT/article.html

You can find the corresponding file using the Java model, where you can insert your own method bodies as strings; or you can parse the corresponding Java file into an AST, and then alter this model programmatically.